# character array comparison ignoring case

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I am working on a project for my Intro to Java class that requires me to compare two characters from two arrays and see if they are the same, ignoring the case of the letter. It compares an answer key of correct answers to a student's test answers. If the student's answer does not match the answer key answer, it should add to the number of incorrect questions.

This is the code I have so far:

```
   public static int gradeExam(char[] correct, char[] student)
   {
      int incorrect = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < correct.length; i++)
      {
         if (!student[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correct[i]))
         {
            incorrect++;
         }
      }
      return incorrect;
   }
```

This is the answer key array:

```
      char[] correct = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                        'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'};
```

When I attempt to compile, I get this error:

```
DriverTest.java:53: error: char cannot be dereferenced
         if (!student[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correct[i]))
                        ^
DriverTest.java:68: error: char cannot be dereferenced
         if(!student[i].equalsIgnoreCase(correct[i]))
                       ^
2 errors
```

I am not sure how else to do this while ignoring the case. I am very new to Java so I apologize if this is an obvious fix. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equalsIgnoreCase` is a `String` method. You can't apply it on `char`s.

You can write

```
if (!Character.toLowerCase(student[i]) == Character.toLowerCase(correct[i]))
```

or

```
if (!Character.toUpperCase(student[i]) == Character.toUpperCase(correct[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change both characters to lowercase with `Character.toLowerCase()` and then do the comparison.

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(student[i]) != Character.toLowerCase(correct[i]))
 {
    incorrect++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Covert both characters in to same case and compare

```
Character.toLowerCase(student[i]) == Character.toLowerCase(correct[i])
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

1. equalsIgnoreCase() is a method of String class, but student[i] is a char not a String.
2. You may compare chars with (==, >, <, != ...)
3. Make char[] student to uppercase first and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Because `char` is primitive type so it don't have method same as `.methodName()`, other way `equalsIgnoreCase()` belong to `String` class. Please change to `Character` (class that wrapper the `char`)

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(student[i]) != Character.toLowerCase(correct[i])) {
    incorrect++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type char is a primitive -- not an object -- so it cannot be dereferenced
You can convert your char to lowercase at both sides:

```
     if (Character.toLowerCase(student[i])!=(Character.toLowerCase(correct[i])))
     {
        incorrect++;
     }
```

Character class is in java.lang package.